# SQL in Eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

how would look this query with eloquent?

```
Select * from tableOne left join tableTwo on (tableOne.ID = tableTwo.ID) where tableOne.Number = 11
```

This is my eloquent statement that I want to change

```
$var = table::where('Number', '=', $varInput)->get();
```

Comment: Are define relation ship with table two in table model ?

Comment: No, I have to do this?

Comment: any error given? and what about tableOne.ID = tableTwo.ID ?

Comment: `DB::table('tableOne')->join('tableTwo', 'tableOne.id', '=', 'tableTwo.id')->where('tableOne.Number', '=', $varInput)->get();`

Comment: Please If your problem has not been solved yet let us know otherwise it would be great if you accept one of the answers below so the community members know that your problem is solved or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amr Aly is correct that you can solve this with:

```
DB::table('tableOne')->join('tableTwo', 'tableOne.id', '=', 'tableTwo.id')->where('tableOne.Number', '=', $varInput)->get();
```

However; I would strongly recommend you look into taking advantage of Eloquent and defining relationships. If your models were setup properly you could do something like the following:

```
$tableOne = TableOne::with('tableTwo')->find($id);
$tableTwo = $tableOne->tableTwo;
```

You can read more about defining relationships in the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships).